# is there a way to display an image over image in pySimpleGui?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

> i am trying to make a  changble speedometer is there a way to display one image over image in pySimpleGui

```
import PySimpleGUI as gui


layout = [[gui.Image(filename = 'cardashboard\Speedometer.png')],
          [gui.Image(filename = 'cardashboard\Arrow.png')]]
window = gui.Window("Car Dashboard", layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == gui.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
      
window.close()
```

Comment: You can use method `draw_image` of Graph element to draw images at any location in Graph element, not for Image element.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as [Jason Yang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71816417/is-there-a-way-to-display-an-image-over-image-in-pysimplegui#comment126910242_71816417) mentioned it is possible with `draw_image` of `Graph` element:

```
import PySimpleGUI as psg

psg.theme('DarkAmber')
layout = [[(psg.Graph((400, 190), (0, 0), (400, 190), key='Graph'))]]
window = psg.Window('Car Dashboard', layout, finalize=True)
window['Graph'].draw_image(filename='Speedometer.png', location=(0, 200))
window['Graph'].draw_image(filename='Arrow.png', location=(190, 170))
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == psg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

window.close()
```

[image: Car Dashboard]